# Two Uniform Independent Random Variables: When is one greater?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

You have two independent random variables: $X$ and $Y$, which are both uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$.

Consider the inequality $X^2- 4Y < 0$. What percentage of the time is the inequality true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want the probability that $Y\gt \frac{X^2}{4}$.

Draw the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$ where the joint density function "lives." Draw the parabola $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$. We want the probability that $(X,Y)$ ends up in the part $P$ of the square which is above the parabola.

Since the joint density is $1$, this probability is the *area* of $P$.  The picture shows that this area is
$$\int_0^1 \left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\,dx.$$
It is somewhat more pleasant to find instead the area of the *rest* of the square. This is 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{4}\,dx,$$
which is $\frac{1}{12}$. Thus the required probability is $\frac{11}{12}$.